# "NOT IN"/"NOT EXISTS" for pairwise column comparison not working in Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I would like to rewrite the below statement in redshift. Redshift does not support IN/NOT IN for multiple column comparison. I get the following error when I try the same query with NOT EXISTS as well:

Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

```
select count(distinct item) from tbl1  
where (item,store) not in (
select distint item, store form tbl1 
where *store changed* -- some filters
)
```

Comment: What is your NOT EXISTS query version?

Comment: @Serg - Here is the not exists version: SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item) AS cnt
FROM tbl1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl1 t2
    WHERE t2.item = t1.item AND
          t2.store = t1.store AND *other filters*
)

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: @Serg Is there any other alternative I can try out ?

Comment: As a side note: the `distinct` inside the sub-query is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tim's idea seems cool, but you can also use the following code:

```
select     count(distinct t1.item)
from       tbl1 t1
left join
(
        select distinct item, store
        form   tbl1 
        where  *store changed* -- some filters
) t2
on t2.item = t1.item
and t2.store = t1.store

where t2.item is null
and   t2.store is null
```

Answer (score 0):

Your version of Redshift does not support this tuple syntax.  You may rephrase as follows:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item) AS cnt
FROM tbl1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM tbl1 t2
    WHERE t2.item = t1.item AND
          t2.store = t1.store AND
          (other filters here...)
);
```

Comment: I am getting the same error with not exists as well - [Amazon] Invalid operation: This type of correlated subquery pattern is not supported due to internal error;

Comment: @AarthiShankar I don't know exactly what you are running.  The `NOT EXISTS` pattern should be supported by Redshift, I think.

Comment: Here is what I am running with "NOT EXISTS": SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT item) AS cnt FROM tbl1 t1 WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM tbl1 t2 WHERE t2.item = t1.item AND t2.store = t1.store AND other filters )